# automatically add an image to the appropriate page in PDF file then save the PDF as a new file Python

Tags: python, image, pdf, tkinter, text

I am writing a small program to automate some of the repetitive tasks at my company. basically the user will select and open a PDF, click on "convert file", the program will add appropriate image to pages with certain text, if a page contain text "Orange CO.", it will add an orange CO image to the page, if a page contain text "Hillsborough CO.", then the program will add a Hillsborough CO image to that page...etc. After the images are added, the program will ask the user to save the PDF as a new file.

This is what I have so far, I kept getting an error "str object has no attribute 'searchFor'". Being brand new to Python, I really need some help on this...

```
import tkinter
import fitz
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog


main_win = tkinter.Tk()
main_win.geometry("500x500")
main_win.sourceFolder = ''
main_win.sourceFile = ''

def chooseFile():
    main_win.sourceFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=main_win, initialdir= "/", title='Please select the PDF file for conversion')
        
def convertFile():
    if main_win.sourceFile:
        for page in main_win.sourceFile:
            text = "Hillsborough County"
            text_instances = page.searchFor(text)
            img_filename = 'hillsborough county stamp.png'

    for inst in text_instances:
        img_rect = fitz.Rect(55, 28, 180, 390)
        document = fitz.open(main_win.sourceFile) 
        page = document[0]
        page.insertImage(img_rect, filename=img_filename)

    if main_win.sourceFile:
        for page in main_win.sourceFile:
            text = "Orange County"
            text_instances = page.searchFor(text)
            img_filename = 'orange county stamp.png'

    for inst in text_instances:
        img_rect = fitz.Rect(55, 28, 180, 390)
        document = fitz.open(main_win.sourceFile) 
        page = document[0]
        page.insertImage(img_rect, filename=img_filename)

b_chooseFile = tkinter.Button(main_win, text = "Choose File", width = 20, height = 3, command = chooseFile)
b_chooseFile.place(x = 250,y = 50)
b_chooseFile.width = 100

b_convertFile = tkinter.Button(main_win, text = "Convert File", width = 20, height = 3, command = convertFile)
b_convertFile.place(x = 250,y = 200)

# Save As feature
def file_save_as(self):
    fout = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = '.pdf')
    try:
        with open(fout, 'w') as output:
            for x in self.entries:
                output.write(x.get())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Cancelled save or error in filename")
    document.close()

main_win.mainloop()
print(main_win.sourceFolder)
print(main_win.sourceFile )
```

Comment: You are basically doing procedural programming. You are basically calling a function before it is defined. What you should do is move the ```chooseFile``` and ```convertFile``` before you are defining the buttons

Comment: Thanks Sujay, I have moved the buttons to the end. Now I got a new error message when I run it, "str object has no attribute 'searchFor'

Comment: ```for page in main_win.sourceFile:``` you are iterating over the **letters** of the string